# Import object from file without running that file's imports

Tags: python

Not sure this is possible, but would like to know if there are any suggestions.

Say I have a file foo.py which looks like

```
import doesnotexist

bar = "Hello, World!"
```

I want to do a `from foo import bar`, but this will fail due to the import not existing in the scope of this new file.

One way of doing this is putting `bar` in a new file called `bar.py` and have `foo.py` also import that, but would like to skip that if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is rather vague; why not catch the exception raised by `import doesnotexist`?

Comment: No, because then you won't get `bar`

Comment: I meant *inside foo.py*. You cannot get `bar` from a module with a runtime exception otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to import only part of a module - Python will load the entire module before pulling the parts you asked for.

As mentioned in the comments, you can capture the import error inside the module and ignore it. Your code will then generate an error if you try to use the module that didn't import.

```
try:
    import doesnotexist
except ImportError:
    pass

bar = "Hello, World!"
```